# Verify mountpoint in the remote server

Tags: python, python-2.7

os.path.ismount() will verify whether the given path is mounted on the local linux machine. Now I want to verify whether the path is mounted on the remote machine. Could you please help me how to achieve this.

For example: my dev machine is : xx:xx:xxx

I want to verify whether the '/path' is mounted on yy:yy:yyy.

How can achieve this by using os.path.ismount() function

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want to verify that `/path` on your machine is pointing to a remote server, or do you want to login to a remote server, and then check if `/path` is a valid mount there.

Comment: My requirement is login to remote server and then check if /path is mounted

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to use SSH from Python? This is a very common FAQ; a common answer is Paramiko.

Comment: No. I know how to use SSH. I will login to remote server using SSH. After logging into server, how can i verify whether the /path is mounted

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to both machines, then one way could be to leverage python's sockets. The client on the local machine would send a request to the server on the remote machine, then the server would do os.path.ismount('/path') and send back the return value to the client.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this. I mean how to send the requests to the server from the client using python sockets. Thanks in advance

Comment: @VasanthaKumari This might help: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example

Comment: @VasanthaKumari Once you are on the page, change the 3.4 to 2 in the url :) . Also, please start considering python 3 https://pythonclock.org/